# Extract github branch from JIRA ticket

Tags: rest, api, github, jira, jira-rest-api

How to extract `github` branch information from a `JIRA` ticket via `JIRA REST API`. This information can be  viewed under 'Development' section of the ticket but the `rest API` call returns empty `JSON`.

Query:

```
<server-url>/rest/dev-status/latest/issue/detail?issueId=<numeric-id>&applicationType=github&dataType=pullrequest
```

Results:

```
{"errors":[],"detail":[]}
```

The user that trying this query has administrator access to `JIRA`.

Any suggestion on how to do this?

Comment: I believe you're using an unpublished API which is always a risk. Your query format for the API seems to be valid based on the community posts that I have seen. 

I was unable to find any public facing JIRA instance that uses a Github integration like you do, so I wasn't able to look further into the issue. (The public instances that I came across use some sort of automation to track Github branches using comments rather that under the Development section)

Comment: Hi @JohnSPerayil, What kind of automation tool that is used to update the Github branches in comments section. Can you share some details?

Comment: I'm not sure about the exact tools being used but I've seen two approaches. An example of the first is the comments in [this](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/GODRIVER-1086) issue. Another approach I've seen is to make it part of [issue links](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-12530).